# Изменение типа столбца наследованной таблицы PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, наследование, partition

Есть основная таблица, содержащая финансовые проводки, и есть куча помесячных партиций этой таблицы, добавленных через наследование. Возникла потребность заархивировать часть старых данных следующим образом: создать новую таблицу через like *ИМЯ_ПАРТИЦИИ* с сохранением зависимостей, заполнить эту таблицу через селект из этой же *партиции*, сагрегировав финансовые проводки до месяца и контрагента, затем убрать наследование с *партиции*, добавить наследование на таблицу-агрегат и дропнуть *партицию*.

Однако при попытке произвести агрегацию обнаружилось, что сумма за месяц **не помещается в текущий размер поля с типом numeric(11,4)**. Альтерить родительскую таблицу и все зависимые следом, чтобы увеличить размер поля numeric, возможности нет: высоконагруженная БД, через которую проходит порядка 7-10 финансовых операций в секунду, самих партиций больше ста, а суммарное количество только живых строк стремится к полутора миллиардам. Создать таблицу без зависимостей с измененным типом также нет возможности, поскольку с родительской таблицы питается довольно много сервисов.

Какие есть варианты для обхода данной проблемы? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Классический подход, который сработает в любой ситуации - это сделать миграцию в несколько шагов, так чтобы каждый можно было сделать без операций, которые требуют останавливать систему.

В данном случае что-то в таком духе:

1. добавляем в родительскую таблицу новое (уже расширенное) поле без значения по умолчанию (то что без значения по-умолчанию - важно. Это быстрая операция даже на большой таблице)
2. добавляем триггер, который автоматически копирует значение из старого поля в новое, для всех новых/измененных записей
3. теперь копируем значение из старого поля в новое. Только делаем это не одной гигантской операцией, а что-то типа `WITH BATCH_TO_UPDATE AS (SELECT id FROM T WHERE NEW_VALUE IS NULL LIMIT 1000) UPDATE T SET NEW_VALUE = OLD_VALUE WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM BATCH_TO_UPDATE)` в цикле. Это можно делать неспешно, не останавливая систему, вожможно в часы, когда нагрузка поменьше и т.д. Конкретную форму этой операции нужно протестировать, конечно. Тут возможно потребуется создать индексы на `new_value` или использовать другой способ разбивки на пачки (может по id, если он из sequence генерируется - тут уж зависит от структуры таблицы). Думаю, основная идея понятна.
4. когда процес в п. 3 закончится, у всех записей в в приложении в новом поле будет правильное значение. Теперь переключаемся на использование нового поля в приложении.
5. удаляем старое поле
6. делаем агрегацию как планировали